# Adding L.Control.Draw to Leaflet manually

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to add a draw control to my leaflet map like this:

```
const drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map)

map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems
  }
}))
```

But I always get this error in the `_initModeHandler` method of `leaflet.draw.js`

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'polyline' of undefined
```

Seems like `this._modes[type] = {};` fails because `this._modes` is `undefined`.

I tried to make `this._modes` an object if `undefined` but this just threw another error anbout how an `addToolbar` method is `undefined`, too.

Comment: What versions of Draw and Leaflet are you using?

Comment: Leaflet 0.7.5 with Leaflet.draw 0.2.3

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Leaflet-Toolbar was the cause of the error. It overrides the `L.Toolbar` definition of Leaflet-Draw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error came from another `L.Toolbar` class that did override the one supplied by Leaflet.draw.

The other `L.Toolbar` didn't set `this._modes` in `initialize()`